# How to list backup files missing corresponding real files?

Tags: bash, grep, backup, file-search

I accidentally deleted some files spread across my home directory, but I do not know exactly which ones were removed. How can I get a list of all backup files missing their corresponding file? (equivalently, files having names ending with a tilde, without there being another file in the same directory with the same name sans trailing tilde?)

I tried a few things so far; although I don't remember the exact flags, it was something like:

```
grep -Rlv '(.*)\n\\1~|.*(?!~)'
```

That didn't work, and neither did:

```
ls -R | grep -v '(.*)\n\\1~|.*(?!~)'
```

How can I find these files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just find all files with a tilde, remove the tilde and look for the "original":

```
find . -name '*~' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do 
  [ -e "${file%\~}" ] ||  echo cp "$file" "${file%\~}"; done 
done
```

**Explanation:**

- `find ~/ -name '*~' -print0` :  find all files in `$HOME` that end in a tilde and print them with the null (`\0`) character. The last is necessary to deal with weird file names that contain newlines etc.
- `while IFS= read -r -d '' file;` : read each file found by `find` into $file`.

- `IFS=` : turns of bash's automatic split at whitespace
- `-r` : treat backslashes literally  (not as escape characters)
- `-d ''` : sets the input field delimiter to the null character.

- `"${file%\~}"` : removes the tilde, see [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)
- `[ -e "${file%\~}" ] || echo cp "$file" "${file%\~}"` : the echo will be run only if the file name (sans tilde) does not exist. To actually copy the files, just remove the `echo`.

Answer (score 3):

In zsh, you can use a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to filter matches. The `e` modifier lets you specify arbitrary code; it's easier on the parsing to write a function and call it with the `+` modifier.

```
zsh -c 'deleted() [[ ! -e ${REPLY%\~} ]]; ls -ld -- **/*\~(+deleted)'
```

If zsh isn't available, you can use find.

```
find ~ -name '*~' -type f -exec sh -c '[ -e "${1%\~}" ] || ls -ld "$1"' sh {} ';'
```

or, faster:

```
find ~ -name '*~' -type f -exec sh -c 'for f do [ -e "${f%\~}" ] || ls -ld "$f"; done' sh {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method to using find. Cache both lists of files (stripping "~") and diff the two anonymous named pipes storing each set.

```
diff <(ls -R *[^~] | xargs -n 1 readlink -f)  <(ls -R *[~] | xargs -n 1 readlink -f | sed 's/~$//')
```